# Question about comeager set in a Polish space

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to understand a proposition of A. Kechris in chapter 8 of his  [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387943749), in which given a non empty metrizable separable space $X$ that is dense in a Polish space $Y$, we have to prove that if $X$ is comeager in $Y$ then $X$ is *Choquet* i.e. the second player has a winning strategy in the Choquet game on $X$. Of course, $X$ contains an intersection of open and dense subsets $W_n$ of  $Y$ , that also must be dense because $Y$ is Baire. What is the winning strategy for II? I put $V_n=U_n\cap W_n$ but I'm not sure that is correct.

Comment: Perhaps an indication of how the Choquet game goes might be of use (that is, where $U$s and $V$s come from).

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder: The *Choquet game* on $X$ has two players ($I$ and $II$) who alternatively choose open sets in $X$ (resp., $U_n$ and $V_n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$) subject to the condition $U_n\supseteq V_n\supseteq U_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$. Player $II$ wins a round if 
$$
\bigcap_n U_n =\bigcap_n V_n \neq \emptyset.
$$

In this context, your proposed strategy won't work as it stands, but almost does. Assume $X= Y = (0,1) =W_n$ for all $n$ and $I$ plays $U_n=(0,\frac{1}{n})$. This example makes it clear that you should use the completeness of $\bigcap_n W_n$ somewhere.

Getting into the argument, $G = \bigcap_n W_n \subseteq X$ is Polish with the relative topology; choose a complete metric $d$ for it. Now the strategy for $II$ is to take $V_n\subseteq U_n\cap W_n$ such that $\overline{V_n}\subseteq U_n$ and $\mathrm{diam}(V_n)<2^{-n}$. Since $W_n$ is open and dense, we can ensure that each such $V_n$ will be nonempty; let $x_n\in V_n$. It is easy to see that $\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy in $G$, so it converges to $x\in G$. This $x$ must belong to
$$
\bigcap_n \overline{V_n} =\bigcap_n U_n,
$$
hence II wins this play.

Answer (score 0):

As $Y$ is a Polish space, in particular $Y$ is completely metrizable, therefore $Y$ is Choquet. Also $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}W_{n}$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$ set in $Y$, it follows that  $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}W_{n}$ is also Choquet. Then using the winning strategy of Player II in the Choquet game played in $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}W_{n}$, we can build a winning strategy for Player II in the Choquet game played in $X$.